# Solve error javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException without enabling Less secure apps access

Tags: java, sendmail, google-authentication

I am trying to send mail in Java and am getting the error `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`. I tried to fix it and turned on Less secure apps access. But starting May 30 2022 [Google has disabled this feature](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en). Is there any other way I can send email using Java?

Comment: The very page you linked to suggests using an app password. Did you try that? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

This will work: https://www.lifewire.com/get-a-password-to-access-gmail-by-pop-imap-2-1171882

Also, this part is very important: "If you don't see App passwords as an option, you must first turn on 2-Step Verification for Gmail."